# Pass a function as a parameter in Java using Reflection

Tags: java

In Java, how can one pass a function as an argument of another function using reflection?.

```
Method method = getMethod("myMethod");
MyInterface myInterface = method; // does not work

MyInterface myInterface2 = this::myMethod; // works

public void myMethod(String string) {
    Logger.getGlobal().info(string);
}

public interface MyInterface {
    void someMethod(String string);
}
```

Comment: As if lambda function?

Comment: `this::myMethod` is a *method reference*, which is one of 2 ways to implement a *functional interface* (the other is a *lambda expression*), and has **nothing** whatsoever to do with *reflection*.

Comment: Please consider this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do something like:

```
MyInterface myInterface = s -> {
    try {
        method.invoke(this, s);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
};
```

Not pretty, isn't it? That is because to invoke a method that you got using reflection, you need to call `invoke`, which throws some checked exceptions. Your functional interface `MyInterface` doesn't throw those checked exceptions, so you would need to catch them.

If `MyInterface` were instead something like:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void someMethod(String string) throws Exception;
}
```

Then you would be able to just do:

```
MyInterface myInterface = s -> method.invoke(this, s);
```

Method references are still impossible though, since `invoke` takes 2 arguments. Method references would have been possible if `MyInterface` were something like:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void someMethod(SomeType t, String string) throws Exception;
}
```

where `SomeType` is the type of `this`. Then you'd be able to do:

```
MyInterface myInterface = method::invoke;
```

But note that this is semantically different from `s -> method.invoke(this, s)`. The above is equivalent to the method reference `SomeType::method`, rather than `this::method`.

Comment: Catching, then printing and otherwise ignoring an exception ... *<shudders>* ... Please, Oh Please!, stop teaching newbies and other naive people this anti-pattern!!!!

Comment: @Andreas Maybe I'm not making this clear. I'm not endorsing that at all. (quote: "Not pretty, isn't it?") Over half of my answer is **not** about that.

Comment: For some reason, reflection is always criticized on SO.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I wasn't criticizing reflection, I was criticizing the very bad example of writing `catch (...) { printStackTrace(); }`, which "ignores" the exception and lets the code keep running as-if nothing was wrong. That anti-pattern is the cause of so many problems, that would should never show it without a description of why it is bad or why it is ok in this case. *"Not pretty, isn't it?"* certainly doesn't cover that. The simple throw of a `RuntimeException` at least makes the error propagate, and this answer now got my up-vote.